# My picture is half way off the page in mobile, perfectly centred in desktop

Tags: css, image

On the page, http://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/11/grey-hat/london/england/clothes/, for example, when looked at on mobile device, my picture is half way off the page,  and seems slightly distorted. On desktop - fine.

I've tried every piece of css i know. The right selector is. awpcp-ad-primary-image.

So:

```
.awpcp-ad-primary-image {
         transform: translate(-28%, -25%);
} 
awpcp-ad-primary-image {
       float: left;       
       background-size: contain; 
       height: auto; 
       width: auto; 
       width 100% //and everything in between plus more. 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: .thumbnail>img - CSS when removed from your code on mobile size the image seems to fit in good

Comment: Oh great. Is there css to remove it?

Comment: Yes. Although i wouldnt recommend this.....

Yes. the css attached to ".thumbnail>img" when removed work with the mobile size. You might need to use media-queries to achieve that as once this is removed normally the desktop view gets distorted.

But Given that the code you have written is not well written...If you restructure the code properly u can solve the problem with doing media queries or any hack.

Comment: @media. thumbnail>img {display: none;}?

Comment: Yeah. I found a solution. Not ideal but hey. The initial problem was that the image was too small and didn't have a border box. Thanks anyway.